# How to join a thread in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

The main question is: How we can wait for a thread in Linux kernel to complete? I have seen a few post concerned about proper way of handling threads in Linux kernel but i'm not sure how we can wait for a single thread in the main thread to be completed (suppose we need the thread[3] be done then proceed):

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

void *func(void *arg) {
    // doing something
    return NULL;
}

int init_module(void) {
    struct task_struct* thread[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        thread[i] = kthread_run(func, (void*) arg, "Creating thread");
    }
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk("cleaning up!\n");
}
```

Comment: Userspace thread, or kthread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there is no equivalent of `pthread_join()` in kernel. Also, I feel like your pattern (of starting bunch of threads and waiting only for one of them) is not really common in kernel. That being said, there kernel does have few synchronization mechanism that may be used to accomplish your goal.

Note that those mechanisms will not guarantee that the thread finished, they will only let main thread know that they finished doing the work they were supposed to do. It may still take some time to really stop this tread and free all resources.

## Semaphores

You can create a locked semaphore, then call `down` in your main thread. This will put it to sleep. Then you will `up` this semaphore inside of your thread just before exiting. Something like:

```
struct semaphore sem;

int func(void *arg) {
    struct semaphore *sem = (struct semaphore*)arg; // you could use global instead

    // do something

    up(sem);
    return 0;
}

int init_module(void) {
    // some initialization
    init_MUTEX_LOCKED(&sem);
    kthread_run(&func, (void*) &sem, "Creating thread");
    down(&sem); // this will block until thread runs up()
}
```

This should work but is not the most optimal solution. I mention this as it's a known pattern that is also used in userspace. Semaphores in kernel are designed for cases where it's mostly available and this case has high contention. So a similar mechanism optimized for this case was created.

## Completions

You can declare completions using:

```
struct completion comp;
init_completion(&comp);
```

or:

```
DECLARE_COMPLETION(comp);
```

Then you can use `wait_for_completion(&comp);` instead of `down()` to wait in main thread and `complete(&comp);` instead of `up()` in your thread.

Here's the full example:

```
DECLARE_COMPLETION(comp);
struct my_data {
    int id;
    struct completion *comp;
};

int func(void *arg) {
    struct my_data *data = (struct my_data*)arg;
    // doing something

    if (data->id == 3)
        complete(data->comp);

    return 0;
}

int init_module(void) {
    struct my_data *data[] = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_data)*N, GFP_KERNEL);

    // some initialization
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        data[i]->comp = &comp;
        data[i]->id = i;
        kthread_run(func, (void*) data[i], "my_thread%d", i);
    }
    wait_for_completion(&comp); // this will block until some thread runs complete()
}
```

## Multiple threads

I don't really see why you would start 5 identical threads and only want to wait for 3rd one but of course you could send different data to each thread, with a field describing it's id, and then call `up` or `complete` only if this id equals 3. That's shown in the completion example. There are other ways to do this, this is just one of them.

## Word of caution

Go read some more about those mechanisms before using any of them. There are some important details I did not write about here. Also those examples are simplified and not tested, they are here just to show the overall idea.

Comment: How do you associate the `struct completion` with a single thread if there are bunch of threads? @ krzysztof

Comment: @Farhad: If you only want to wait for one thread, you don't have to do that. You can pass it to all threads and ignore it in all but one thread. Only this one will call `complete`.

Comment: if this is the general thread function:                                                    `void *func(void *arg) {
    struct completion comp;
    init_completion(&comp);
    // doing something
    return NULL;
}`
how can you call the `wait_for_competion(&comp)` in the main thread and it  affects only one thread?

Comment: @Farhad: It's wrong way of doing this. You should do this exactly as it's described in semaphore example - you declare completion in main tread and pass it to thread functions. I've added full example with multiple threads and completion.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: None of these sync mechanism is sufficient for being sure, that thread function is ended. This is because signal actions are performed **inside that function**, not after it. As a result, the function may be executed even after the module, containing function's code, have been unloaded. This will leads to crash.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I agree that those mechanisms will not let you wait for thread function end. They will, however, let you wait until the function finishes its work (which is what you usually really need). You can, after all, decide when to call `complete` or `up`. The thread may still live for some time and may use it's resources but that's unimportant in most cases. It is a good point, however, so I'll update my answer.

Comment: What if we wanted to generalize either the semaphore or the completion example to wait for all threads spawned instead of just one?

Answer (score 5):

*kthread_stop()* is a kernel's way for wait thread to end.

Aside from waiting, *kthread_stop()* also sets *should_stop* flag for waited thread and wake up it, if needed. It is usefull for threads which repeat some actions infinitely.

As for single-shot tasks, it is usually simpler to use works for them, instead of kthreads.

**EDIT**:
Note: *kthread_stop()* can be called only when kthread(task_struct) structure is not freed.

Either thread function should return only after it found *kthread_should_stop*() return true, or *get_task_struct*() should be called before start thread (and put_task_struct() should be called after *kthread_stop()*).

Comment: so where is the distinction between `join`  and `exit` in kernel thread implementation?

Comment: `join` is performed by the *other* thread, `exit` is performed by the thread *itself*. *should_stop* flag is actually a **hint** to the thread: "other thread waits me to terminate". It is up to the thread to check that flag and react, if it is set. There is no way to `kill` kernel thread.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: As you wrote `kthread_stop()` will wake the thread. That is quite important and exactly why I wouldn't use it as a general "join" replacement. Well, at least when using `kthread_run`. It may be better suited for `kthread_create`, though.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: As most waits are actually event-waits, spurious wake up from `kthread_stop()` is not a problem. From the other side, `kthread_stop()` is the only way to destroy kthread and free resources.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: But it can screw up if you're sleeping. I don't get your 2nd sentence, though. Kthread will be destroyed and resources will be freed when it calls `do_exit()` (which will be run automatically when returning). Also, calling `kthread_stop` on a task that already ended is not safe as `do_exit()` will end up in calling `put_task_struct()` which will free the `task_struct`. So this technique is useful but with some caution. I think I will edit my answer to describe all those details.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: `do_exit` *does not destroy* task structure: the last instruction before `schedule()` is `tsk->flags |= PF_NOFREEZE`. Actual task destruction is performed by `kthread_stop` via `put_task_struct()`. As for screwing up by  `kthread_stop`, it is not a problem as every sleeping is actual a wait-for-event-become-true. So, if event does not become true when thread is awoken, sleeping is repeated.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I agree that there are very few situations where waking up a thread may be a problem. However I still believe that `do_exit` *will* destroy the task. It will set `tsk->state = TASK_DEAD` and then call `schedule()`. That will make `finish_task_switch()` call `put_task_struct()`. Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kadamski/69ea849f9564d0b9a8c1) - it oopses on my system.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: Hmm, you seem to be right, `do_exit()` also destroys task structure, if called without `kthread_stop()`. At least, *kthread_stop*'s description prohibits to call `kthread_stop()` after `do_exit()`. Your original example also crashes for me (it works if `kthread_stop` is moved into module_exit, but that fact does not mean that it is a correct usage). But that leads to a problem: when module is unloaded, kthread function's code is freed; how one can be confident that this code has already been completed?