# Linux - Control Flow in a linux kernel module

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am learning to write kernel modules and in one of the examples I had to make sure that a thread executed 10 times and exits, so I wrote this according to what I have studied:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>

struct task_struct *ts;
int flag = 0;
int id = 10;

int function(void *data) {
  int n = *(int*)data;
  set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
  schedule_timeout(n*HZ); // after doing this it executed infinitely and i had to reboot 
  while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Ding");
  }
  flag = 1;
  return 0;
}

int init_module (void) {
  ts = kthread_run(function, (void *)&id, "spawn");
  return 0;
}

 void cleanup_module(void) {
   if (flag==1) { return; }
   else { if (ts != NULL) kthread_stop(ts);
   }
   return;
 }

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

What I want to know is :
a) How to make thread execute 10 times like a loop 
b) How does the control flows in these kind of processes that is if we make it to execute 10 times then does it go back and forth between `function` and `cleanup_module` or `init_module` or what exactly happens?

Answer (score 2):

If you control kthread with `kthread_stop`, the kthread *shouldn't exit until be ing stopped* (see also that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29964567/3440745)). So, after executing all operations, kthread should wait until stopped.

Kernel already implements `kthread_worker` mechanism, when kthread just executes works, added to it.

```
DEFINE_KTHREAD_WORKER(worker);

struct my_work
{
    struct kthread_work *work; // 'Base' class
    int n;
};

void do_work(struct kthread_work *work)
{
    struct my_work* w = container_of(work, struct my_work, work);

    printk(KERN_EMERG "Ding %d", w->n);

    // And free work struct at the end
    kfree(w);
}

int init_module (void) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        struct my_work* w = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_work), GFP_KERNEL);
        init_kthread_work(&w->work, &do_work);
        w->n = i + 1;
        queue_kthread_work(&worker, &w->work);
    }
    ts = kthread_run(&kthread_worker_fn, &worker, "spawn");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    kthread_stop(ts);
}
```